# Openlayers 3, getfeatureinfo and geowebcache

Tags: openlayers, geowebcache, getfeatureinfo

I am having a bit of trouble using the getGetFeatureInfo function on the TileWMS source in OL3. It works, but it represents the X/Y-parameters as I/J in the generated URL.

```
/geowebcache/service/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=mylayer&LAYERS=mylayer&SRS=EPSG%3A32633&CQL_FILTER=TIME%20TEQUALS2015-12-07T18%3A00%3A00)&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&FEATURE_COUNT=50&**I=162&J=125**&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A32633&BBOX=294656%2C6706272%2C316320%2C6727936&callback=
```

This gives me the following error:

> 400: The parameters for x and y must both be positive integers.

If I exchange I for X and J for Y in the above URL, it works fine.

How can I make this work? Is the some setting in geowebcache that can be used for it to accept I/J? Or can I do something in OL3 to make it generate X/Y instead of I/J?

Comment: What if you specify WMS version 1.1.0 for the TileWMS, that should force X/Y image coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

A GetFeatureInfo request sends image coordinates to a Web Map Service for a corresponding GetMap request (the result of which is an image).

In a WMS version 1.3.0 the image coordinates are sent as I,J.  In a WMS versions 1.1.1, and below, the image coordinates are sent as X,Y.

If you send your image coordinates as X,Y to a WMS 1.3.0 version service, the server is fully at liberty to reject the request, or respond with an error.

If geowebcache is expecting X,Y for a WMS 1.3.0 GetFeatureInfo request then that is a bug with geowebcache (you should report your issue here: https://github.com/GeoWebCache/geowebcache/issues).  OpenLayers is working correctly sending I,J.

One *solution* would be to force using WMS 1.1.1 in your request, OL will send X,Y and geowebcache will work.

Otherwise you could look to replicate I and J, as X and Y (so your request includes I,J and X,Y coordinates).